# Propel 2.0 model:build cannot find database

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I'm trying to reverse engineer a database with Propel 2. But every time i try to run the model:build command i get the following error:

```
[Propel\Generator\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
Invalid database name: no configured connection named 'default'
```

It says "no configured connection"?? but is was able to generate a schema.xml from the database with the "reverse" command?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did u create the [configuration file](http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html#tabphp)?

Comment: Yes i did create a configuration file but it was different from the one in your link. It worked though! thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I found that I am having similar situation.

```
<database name="somename" ...>
```

Change the **`name`** attribute in **`<database>`** in the generated schema.xml to match the connection name in your propel.yaml may solve the problem.

```
database:
  connections:
      somename:
          adapter: mysql
```